# difference between two times in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi All
im trying to build a simple form that the user use it to enter his leave request.
the form contains from time input field and to time input field,and these two filds  will contains values in this syntax:
from time: 15:59 pm
to time:   16:59 pm

i have two questions:
1. what is the Datatype that i should use to store p.m and am in the record in mysql database,  and not only the time?(i try to use Time,DateTime Date) but these datatypes only stores the time without p.m,a.m
2. what is the best way to calculate the diffrence between these two times?  
Thank You

Comment: you need to add am/pm to a 24-hr date format?

Comment: Databases will store times as either seconds elapsed since Jan 1 1970 (UNIX style) or as some ISO formatted sate time such as YYYY-MM-DD:HH:SS. Neither case requires you to store AM or PM asthe former is just a count of elapsed seconds and the latter will use 24 hour clock notation so will be PM if HH is between 12 and 23

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing dates/times I find it easiest to work with a timestamp.
There are tons of date functions in PHP if it's just to output the date in the format you want have a look at [date functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to store times in the database is in 24-hour time and use PHP's `date` function to format the time when you pull it to display it using AM or PM.

To compare two times, I suggest looking at the`strtotime` function. This will return the time in UNIX fashion (seconds). You can then compare which time is greater or less than each other, or even perform basic mathematics operations on them (like determining the amount of seconds between each time and then dividing by 60 to determine minutes, etc).

Answer (score 0):

**question 1**

stored as [`time`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html), which use [ISO 8601 (hh:mm:ss)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times)

**question 2**

use timediff, like

```
select timediff(cast('13:59:29' as time), cast('10:20:00' as time));
>> 03:39:29
```

To display the AM/PM

```
select time_format(cast('13:59:29' as time), '%r');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store it as a timestamp, you can add pm/am automatically when you output:

`print date('G:i a',1294239540); // prints 15:59 pm`

and to get the difference in seconds just use strtotime and substract:

`print (strtotime('16:59') - strtotime('15:59')); //prints 3600 (1 hour in seconds)`

Answer (score 0):

Storing am and pm when you're using 24 format is redundant. Anything ***between*** 11:59 and 00:00 is automatically pm. DateTime/timestamp should be more than sufficient to do what you're trying to accomplish. Then you can convert it using strftime back to 12-hr with am/pm.

Comment: Between 12:00 and 23:59. Any time after noon (12:00) is pm and any time after midnight (00:00) is am

Comment: @Gordon: Correct. My mindset was one you start seeing 13-23 you're in PM and the "pm" flag isn't necessary. Also, i was referencing the between values not the range start/end. ;-) Good catch though, I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0):

1) This doesn't make any sense - the database stores a representation of an exact instant in time, not an ambiguous 12 hour format with no am/pm. Regardless of how the db is storing it, you can just calculate the am or pm:

```
<?php
$am_pm = date('a', $timestamp);
?>
```

or even better, in mysql using your time field:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%p')
```

2) For this you can use either php's [date_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), or in mysql:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(date_one, date_two)
```